# How long does the AFSP(TSA) process take from start to finish for category 3

Tags: tsa

I paid them the $130 fee a week and a half ago and I'm still waiting for their fingerprinting instructions email. If anyone can share their timeline, that would be helpful.

TIA.

Comment: Hi and welcome. As the linked answer shows, *"there's no specific processing time".*